# radio buttons and passing values

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

```js
if(document.getElementById('3w').checked) {
  alert('3w');
}else if(document.getElementById('6w').checked) {
  alert('6w');
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="pnltype" id="3w" value="3w" /> 3W
<input type="radio" name="pnltype" id="6w" value="6w" checked />  6W
```

My problem:
this will run perfectly in firefox. For example, if I tick 3w and than choose "reload", I get alert '3w'
But not in Chrome.
In Chrome although I check 3W, and then manually "reload" the page, 'the alert will be '6w'.
What is the reason?

In previous versions I used the onClick option in the radio buttons and this function:
function radioClick() {            window.location.reload();        }
And again - in firefox it behave as expected, not in chrome

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you have "checked" property in input, on Reload it will always check 6W, that is why the alert shows 6W. i checked with [JSFiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/5k9vpxkx/) it always return 6W, regardless of which browser i use.

Comment: why do you need to reload!!! why not use onclick!!

Answer (score 0):

remove the checked attribute in the second input.

I feel using jquery will be easy for this kind of things. give it a try 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

```
<input type="radio" class="any-name" name="pnltype" id="3w" value="3w" /> 3W
<input type="radio" class="any-name" name="pnltype" id="6w" value="6w"/>  6W

$('.any-name').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yasithao3/j1ujhetd/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this without reload it should work:

```
<script>

function check(){
if(document.getElementById('3w').checked) {
      alert('3w');
    }else if(document.getElementById('6w').checked) {
      alert('6w');
    }
}

</script>
<body onload="check()">
    <input type="radio" name="pnltype" id="3w" value="3w" onclick="check()"/> 3W
    <input type="radio" name="pnltype" id="6w" value="6w" checked  onclick="check()"/>  6W
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following code

```
        <title>Test</title>

        <script>
        function ClickEvent()
        {
            if(document.getElementById('3w').checked) {
              alert('3w');
            }
             if(document.getElementById('6w').checked) {
              alert('6w');
            }
        }
        </script>

        <body>
        <input type="radio" name="pnltype" id="3w" value="3w" onclick=" ClickEvent()" /> 3W
        <input type="radio" name="pnltype" id="6w" value="6w" checked onclick="ClickEvent()" />  6W
        </body>
```